# Why did Jonathan attack the Philistines?

Tags: 1-samuel, philistines

In 1 Samuel 13 Jonathan seemingly unprovoked, attacks the Philistines triggering a war. The text does not indicate that Jonathan was told to do this by Saul, Samuel or God. Further on in the chapter we learn that none of the Jewish army had any weapons other than Saul and Jonathan. The end result was a Jewish victory but that was far from clearly an inevitable outcome when Jonathan acted. I have not found any commentaries which explain Jonathan's motives (Rabbi David Kimchi says he wanted to start a war, but doesn't explain why, with what authority, or why he would think the Jews would win).

Please explain why Jonathan attacked the Philistines and whenever possible cite sources to support your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

While Saul had been anointed as the king of Israel, he did not receive immediate acceptance from the people, as reflected in two significant statements;

1. “Is Saul also among the prophets?” (1 Samuel 10:12)
2. “How can this fellow save us?” (1 Samuel 10:27)

Saul belonged to the tribe of Benjamin, found himself in a precarious position. The land of Benjamin was subject to Philistine dominance, extending beyond his settlement to the east as far as Mismash. In 1 Samuel 13:2, Saul had only 3000 soldiers, relatively small comparing to the Philistine army (1 Samuel 13:5). The victory achieved by Jonathan at Geba represented a rebellious act, aiming at reclaiming Phillistine occupied territory.

Though the scripture does not explicitly state it, there is a notable theme indicating the divine presence with Jonathan in the battles against the Philistine. In the account where Jonathan and his armor-bearer attacked the Philistine outpost on a cliff toward Mismash, the Lord's favor is implied. These two courageous young men showed themselves to the Philistines, who, without resistance, fell before Jonathan. Twenty Philistines were killed (1 Samuel 14:13-14).

1 Samuel 14:15 describe;

> Then panic struck the whole army—those in the camp and field, and those in the outposts and raiding parties—and the ground shook. **It was a panic sent by God.** (NIV)

Subsequent to this victory, 1 Samuel 14:47-48 describes;

> 47 After **Saul had assumed rule over Israel**, he fought against their enemies on every side: Moab, the Ammonites, Edom, the kings of Zobah, and the Philistines. Wherever he turned, he inflicted punishment on them. 48 He fought valiantly and defeated the Amalekites, **delivering Israel from the hands of those who had plundered them.** (NIV)

Despite God's disappointment with Saul, He continued to fortify Saul's position as king, with the ultimate aim of delivering the Israelites from their misery.

Answer (score 0):

This incident is probably one that needs to be seen in the context of finally conquering the whole land.

Just before Joshua died we have his instructions (Joshua 23 & 24) to continue conquering the reminder of the land so that each tribe would receive its full inheritance.  Judges 1:1-26 describes the continuation of Joshua's series of campaigns; however, Judges 1:27-36 also describes the failure to complete these campaigns.

This situation remained the case up to the time of King Saul and David.

Now, concerning Jonathan, Ellicott reports this from Ewald about 1 Sam 13:3 -

> Jonathan throughout this history appears as the perfect type of a
> warrior, according to the requirements of his age; he is everywhere
> the first in courage and activity and speed, slender also, and of
> well-made figure. This personal beauty and swiftness of foot in attack
> or retreat gained for him among the troops the name of “gazelle.” (The
> first lines of the song, 2Samuel 1:19, can only be explained on the
> supposition that Jonathan was well known by this name in the army.)
> “In all this, as in his uprightness and fidelity, he showed himself
> the right worthy son of a king.”—Ewald.

Thus, as the King Saul's son and the heir apparent, Jonathan possible presumed it his responsibility to lead the process of finally clearing the promised land of Israel of its pagan inhabitants so that the tribes could finally take possession of their full inheritance.

With the benefit of historical hindsight, Jonathan's initiative was successful - the land was gradually cleared until the height of David's reign which was absolute.  Indeed, we read that:

> 1 Kings 4:20, 21 - The people of Judah and Israel were as numerous as
> the sand on the seashore, and they were eating and drinking and
> rejoicing. And Solomon reigned over all the kingdoms from the
> Euphrates to the land of the Philistines, as far as the border of
> Egypt. These kingdoms offered tribute and served Solomon all the days
> of his life.

Viewed in this light, Jonathan's initiative was very important to Israel's subsequent history.

Answer (score 0):

There was nothing "unprovoked" about Jonathan's initiative, as we may see from reading the previous chapters. This was one episode in a continuing war which began in 1 Samuel ch13 v5 when the Philistines mustered an army and invaded the territory of the Israelites, establishing an encampment at Michmash. As we may see from vv17-18, the Philistine invaders had not been repulsed and were continuing to raid different Israelite areas. V19, incidentally, explains why the Israelites were short of metal weapons.

So the garrison which Jonathan was attacking was not a frontier post. It was a post deep within Isrealite territory which was being held by an aggressive invader. The only way to repel the invader was to fight back, and that was Jonathan's motive.

He was not guilty of triggering a war, because the war had already been started by the other side. He was guilty only of triggering a battle, as a slightly insubordinate military leader.

Answer (score 0):

Provocation is somewhat irrelevant as far as the Bible is concerned because God had already commanded the Israelites to drive out the Philistines:

Exodus 23:31

> I will set your boundary from the Red Sea to the sea of the
> Philistines, and from the wilderness to the Euphrates River; for I
> will hand over the inhabitants of the land to you, and you will drive
> them out from you.

Perhaps more important is whether Jonathan acted without Saul's knowledge. The text can be read either way:

> 2 Now Saul chose for himself three thousand men of Israel, of whom two
> thousand were with Saul in Michmash and in the hill country of Bethel,
> while a thousand were with Jonathan at Gibeah of Benjamin. But he sent
> the rest of the people away, each to his tent. 3 And Jonathan attacked
> the garrison of the Philistines that was in Geba, and the Philistines
> heard about it. Then Saul blew the trumpet throughout the land,
> saying, “Let the Hebrews hear!”

I understand this as a coordinated effort in which Saul sent Jonathan to engage the Philistines and was ready and waiting to support him once the Philistines responded.

**Conclusion**: The Biblical outlook is that Jonathan was carrying out God's will to drive out the Philistines from the land, whether or not he was provoked in the immediate case.